# Prompt Outlook user to enter the value of a user defined property if not already assigned

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to intercept any new or in reply message and prompt the sender to enter the value for a user defined field if it is not already assigned to the message.

The basic flow should be:
User hits send
Check if field value is empty
IF empty, inputbox to collect the value and apply
Send email

The user defined field is in place and I'm able to create a form template for sending new emails that allows the sender to input the value before sending. This is intended to act as a verification for new messages and to create the opportunity to apply when replying to previous messages.

Answer (score 0):

Trap `Application.ItemSend` event. In the event handler, use the `MailItem.UserProperties` collection to check if the user property is already present. If not, use `InputBox` function to show a prompt. Use the returned value to add a user property using `MailItem.UserProperties.Add`.

Answer (score 0):

The [ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) event of the Application class is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an `Inspector` (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the `Send` button) or when the `Send` method for an Outlook item, such as `MailItem`, is used in a program. Here is the starting point:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)  
 Dim prompt As String  
 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"  
 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then  
   Cancel = True  
 End If  
End Sub
```

But you can use the [InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) function instead of a message box. It displays a prompt in a dialog box, waits for the user to input text or click a button, and returns a string containing the contents of the text box.

```
Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue
Message = "Enter a value between 1 and 3"    ' Set prompt.
Title = "InputBox Demo"    ' Set title.
Default = "1"    ' Set default.
' Display message, title, and default value.
MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
```

Finally, the [UserProperties.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.add) method creates a new user property in the `UserProperties` collection.

```
Sub AddUserProperty(myItem as MailItem) 
 Dim myUserProperty As Outlook.UserProperty 
 
 Set myUserProperty = myItem.UserProperties.Add("SampleTextUserProperty", olText) 
 myUserProperty.Value = "test"

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.  I even tried copying / pasting Microsoft's ItemSend into a class module just to see if that would give me a message box.  Nothing happens.  Am I missing something really basic?